# Keep showing div when not hovering on trigger link anymore

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with the menu I just coded: https://jsfiddle.net/nL124rLq/1/

I am using a general selector (~) on my css and I think this might be a mistake, because it might be the origin of my problem:

```
#nav #link1:hover ~ #flydown {
left:0;
display:block;
}

#nav #link2:hover ~ #flydown {
    left:-100%;
    display:block;
}
```

... and so on.

As you can see, everything works fine but **when I stop hovering on the anchors, the sliding menu under the links disappears**. I understand my code is not made for this to work correctly, but I can't figure out a way of making it work.

I am going to add content (sub-menus) to the coloured areas that form the slider, so they must be clickable and must remain visible when the user hovers over them.

If it's any help, I got the idea from this site: http://www.tiffany.es/

**Thank you** guys very much in advance and excuse the relatively vague question!

Comment: I asked a similar question last year. Maybe it will help you. [Hover over thumbnail image to launch new image; new image persists after hovering ends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836640/hover-over-thumbnail-image-to-launch-new-image-new-image-persists-after-hoverin)

Comment: It does seem like that would work. I am convinced that it should work with CSS only though, and that my problem stems from the structure I'm using on my HTML elements. If all else fails, I will surely use your solution. Thank you!

Comment: You could maybe trigger a forward CSS animation on hover and then overwrite display from there? Similar to what is discussed here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273478/webkit-css-animation-issue-persisting-the-end-state-of-the-animation

Comment: Have you found your answer, I have a very similar problem.

Comment: Yes, it was with the help of @Michael_B I'm posting it now as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution, more or less. @Michael_B 's help was awesome! The resulting code looks horrible though. Oh well, it works!

Basically I added this to every single link that I have on the nav (link1, link2... etc.):

```
$("#link1").on("mouseover", function () {
$(".flydown").addClass('permahover1');
});

$(".flydown").mouseleave(function () {
$(".flydown").removeClass('permahover1');
});
```

...and added the following CSS once for every element in my menu (permahover1, permahover2 etc.) to specify their different positions with left:0%, left:-100%, etc:

```
.flydown.permahover1 {
left:0%;
display:block;
}
```

It got really dirty in no time. But I don't know a better solution. Here's a working JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nL124rLq/4/

As always, **thank you guys** very much for your help!